# Meta tags with Angular 7 Universal not updated in time for crawlers

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I am currently attempting to fix meta tags for a hobby project of mine but it is currently not rendering the meta tags for crawlers. They come from an external API call which I believe might be part of the issue.

I have defined all the tags in index.html and then I am attempting to dynamically update them within various components. Can anyone point out where I go wrong? This is ran with Angular Universal.

```
import { Meta, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

...

export class UpcomingPageComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private contentService: ContentService,
    private deviceService: DeviceService,
    private meta: Meta,
    private titleService: Title
  ) {

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.url_shorthand = params['url_shorthand'];
      this.contentService.get_upcoming_title(this.url_shorthand).subscribe(res => {
        this.content = res;
        this.loaded = true;
        this.titleService.setTitle('GameSentry - ' + this.content.title);

        this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:title', content: 'GameSentry - ' + this.content.title });
        this.meta.updateTag({
          property: 'og:description', content: 'Monetization & microtransaction info for upcoming game '
            + this.content.title
        });
        this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:image', content: this.content.game_cover });
        this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:url', content: 'https://gamesentry.com/upcoming/' + this.content.url_shorthand });
        this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'twitter:card', content: 'summary' });
      });

    });
  }

...
```

Comment: This seems fine. If you view source / curl the SSR copy of the page, what do you see? Does the external API call rely on any authentication? Have you tried adding logging to see what is being executed?

Comment: If I view source I get the meta tags defined in the index.html.
There is no authentication on the external api, although there might be redirection when you mention it as it forces https. In terms of logging it is updated when it receives the data but it seems like it is too slow for crawlers

Comment: It does not seem like it is the issue I mentioned above. Here is an example link https://www.gamesentry.com/upcoming/Cyberpunk-2077 if you check the Elements console it does correctly add the meta tags described above but it is not part of the page source.

Comment: Usually this is because you have some kind of error durring SSR. Check the terminal you started the nodejs process from for any errors

Comment: There are no errors. It is hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk if that makes a difference.

Comment: @dubar I just checked the link you provided and it appears that you've fixed this?

Comment: Yes I did manage to solve it! It had to do with how mobile is loaded, it loaded the wrong version initially due to our implementation method. The solution was to only check if the device was mobile on the clientside rather than server side. This was done with the use of 

     if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platform)) {
      this.mobile = this.deviceService.getDevice();
    }